# SQLAlchemy Alembic: Issue with URL for SQLServer

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate, sqlalchemy-migrate

I was trying to create a database migration script with Alembic for my SQLServer database and having issues with the connection string.

This is what I have now:

```py
sqlalchemy.url = "mssql+pyodbc://db_server/database?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
```

Error message during `alembic current`:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '"mssql+pyodbc://dbserverxx/dbxx?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"'`

I tested my script with SQLite and is working fine.

I'm using a Mac and the contents of `odbcinst.ini` is as follows:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=2
```

I was able to connect to database using PyODBC and execute raw SQLs.

Any suggestions to have the right `sqlalchemy.url` is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the quotes.

This is how my `alembic.ini` has the corresponding line now:

```py
sqlalchemy.url = mssql+pyodbc://dbserver/database?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
```

Answer (score 0):

URLs cannot have spaces. Replace the spaces with `+` characters:

```
sqlalchemy.url = "mssql+pyodbc://db_server/database?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
```

You can learn more about [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP), spaces aren't the only characters that have to be escaped in URLs.

Comment: I tried this and didnt work. However, I was able to resolve it by removing the `"` (quotes)

Comment: Yes, a SQLAlchemy connection URI *should* be encoded, but spaces are actually not the problem (as the other answer shows). AFAIK the only characters which *must* be escaped are `:`, `@`, `/`, and `?` (and maybe `+` itself, not sure about that one).